# How to give options to multiselect dropdown jquery

Tags: jquery, multi-select, dropdown

I am trying to create multi-select drop-down dyanamically.

**Html**

```
<select id="impact-report-type-filter-input" name="impact-report-type-filter-input" multiple='multiple'>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: '',
    minWidth: 165,
    header: "Select Recipient(s)",
});

//in other function im trying this for options

var filterList = data.filterList;  // ["1495cat", "Category Test","Labour", "New Law 1", "testing"]
//var filterString = filterList.toString();
//var dataArray = filterString.split(",");
//var data1="1,2,3,4";
//Make an array
//var dataarray=data1.split(",");
$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").val(dataarray);//filterList);
$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect("refresh");
```

But im not getting any options in dropdown please refer image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. Include bootstrap-multiselect.css also

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //in other function i'm trying this for options
$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: '',
    minWidth: 165,
    header: "Select Recipient(s)",
});
var filterList = ["1495cat", "Category Test","Labour", "New Law 1", "testing"];  // 

for(f in filterList){
    $('#impact-report-type-filter-input').append($('<option>', {
         value: filterList[f],
         text:  filterList[f]
    }));
}
$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect("refresh");   

});
```

Comment: But Shoham, bootstrap do have "rebuild" method to rebuild the plugin. After pushing more options to the dropdown from JS, I rebuild the plugin using .multiselect("rebuild") then only is started forking for me. .multiselect("refresh") is not working for me.

Comment: After selecting/deselecting options from JS we need to do a "refresh". But if you add more options to the dropdown we need to do a "rebuild". Please refer "http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods".